# every other element in a list then reverse

Tags: python

I have a list `a = [2,4,6,8,10]`

I want to get every other value start with the first value at `2` so that would be `2,6,10`. Next I want to reverse this value to become `10,6,2`. What I tried is `a[-1::-2]` to reverse and get every other value. However, currently my list has an odd length. Later on my program it will become even as I start to remove values `2,6,10`. What is left will be `[4,8]` and if I do a[-1::-2] That will not get the first value. I tried `a[::2].reverse()` but that is not allowed. How can I go about doing this

```
ex:

a = [2,4,6,8,10]
#remove every other element starting at index 0
# [2,4,6] --> reverse --> [6,4,2]
a = [4,8]
#remove every other element starting at index 0
# [4] --> reverse --> [4]
a = [8]
```

Comment: I'm not sure how `2,4,10` reverses into `10,6,2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much faster version would be to use second slicing like this

```
a = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
print a[::2][::-1]
print b[::2][::-1]
```

But you can also do it like this, with `reversed` and `list` functions

```
print list(reversed(a[::2]))
print list(reversed(b[::2]))
```

**Output**

```
[10, 6, 2]
[10, 6, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11]

# Works for odd lengths
>>> a[::2][::-1]
[10, 6, 2]
```

What would be more efficient than this compound slicing -

```
>>> a = [2,4,6,8,10,12]
>>> if len(a) % 2 == 0: v = a.pop()
... 
>>> a
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> a[::-2]
[10, 6, 2]
```

Your other example. When it is even.

```
>>> a = [4, 8]
>>> a[-1::-2]
[8]
```

Comment: This will not work if the length of the list is an odd number. He always wants the first number.

Comment: This doesn't work in my situation as `a[::-2]` for `a = [4,8]` will give me `[8]` and that is not the first element in the list but thank you for your input

Comment: Should be good now. Came up with something that should be more efficient.